# Django filter_horizontal pre-selected items

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I want see in django admin filter_horizontal not all my tags, but only tags of one selected group.

Example:
My tags:
Group Fruits:
Apples, Plums, Appricots..
Group Flowers:
Roses, Tulips, Asters..

I want to be able select anywhere in admin one plants group (for example "Fruits") and see in filter_horizontal  tags  "Apples, Plums, Appricots.." , but not "Roses.."
My models:

```
class PlantsGroups(TitleRequiredModel):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class PlantsTags(TitleRequiredModel):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ...
    plants_group = models.ForeignKey(PlantsGroups, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class PlantsTags(TitleRequiredModel):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ...
    plants_tags = models.ManyToManyField('PlantsTags', blank=True, related_name="blabla", verbose_name='blablabla')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Thanks!

I am novice to django, please help me :)